# Post to facebook with multiple cities target

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to post something with target parameters, and i can do that but specifying only one city. Is there any way to pass two or more cities?

I'm trying this way:

```
parameters.targeting = new {
countries = "some country",
cities = new [] { new { key = "city value" }, new { key = "other city value" } },
locales = "locale code"
};
```

But no success! How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is very unclear, but I am guessing you are just not formatting your array of cities correctly. See more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/targeting-specs/

I believe you should be using "name" instead of "key" for the cities, but again I really don't have enough information to go off of.

Comment: I'm not using ads-api, because its a regular post that i'm trying to do. Checking the docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) its not clear how do we need to set the cities values.

Comment: I've change my code and get this work well.
cities = new { "value1,value2,value3" };

Answer (score 0):

> Specify key, radius & distance_unit. For key, see Targeting Search,
>   Cities. radius is a distance around cities, from 10 to 50 miles or 17
>   to 80 kilometers. distance_unit is mile or kilometer. Limit: 250.
>   Example: 'cities': [{'key':'2430536', 'radius':12,
>   'distance_unit':'mile'}]

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api/targeting#location